# How many jobs can jPOS process?

Tags: jpos

I wanted to determine how jPOS handle processes received.
Do jPOS process multiple jobs/threads? If so, how to determine the number of threads that jPOS handles? How to configure multithreading to jPOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the jPOS documentation, in particular the TransactionManager. There's a free book you can get at http://jpos.org/learn